# Is it a bad idea to have more than a custom entity defined in a module?

Tags: entities

**Fact #1**

Drush module exposes two commands `drush generate module-content-entity` and `drush generate module-configuration-entity`, both generating new custom modules with entity classes defined. There is no separate command to generate custom entity code for existing module.

**Fact #2**

I could not find the module in Drupal's core, where a single module defines more than one custom entity (Maybe there are some and I have not seen all). There are modules that register content and configuration entities, but not multiple contents or multiple configuration entity (or block or any other).

---

I have a feeling that, even though it's not forbidden, it's not a good idea to have multiple entities in a single module. Maybe it's an architectural pattern.

Can anyone elaborate on this or share some content (docs, articles) where this is discussed?

Comment: It's entirely fine to have multiple entity types defined in a single module. I've done it on multiple occasions and never run into a single issue on any of the systems by doing so.

Comment: I also, can't see any issues with this. Can you share any core or well-known contributed modules doing so?

Comment: And, any ideas why Drush is forcing us to generate a new module with new entity?

Comment: I guess it was simply much easier to code to generate new files all the time than doing all the diffs/merges required to update an existing module...

Comment: What hudri said.

Comment: I see, but updating is not important. I mean the ability to add a new entity to an existing module.

Comment: Same answer....

Comment: The Commerce module does it: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce/-/tree/8.x-2.x/modules/payment/src/Entity

Comment: In retrospect, Taxonomy in core does it as well, declaring `taxonomy_vocabulary` and `taxonomy_term` in the same module.

Answer (score 5):

### About Fact #1

You can generate multiple entities for a single module directly with the Chi-teck's Drupal Code Generator.

Require the package:

```
composer require chi-teck/drupal-code-generator --dev
```

If you have the latest Drush version this package is already installed.

Run the command `./vendor/bin/dcg` to display the main navigation:

```
./vendor/bin/dcg
 Select generator
  [ 0] ..
  [ 1] Console
  [ 2] Entity
  [ 3] Form
  [ 4] Miscellaneous
  [ 5] Plugin
  [ 6] Service
  [ 7] Test
  [ 8] Yaml
  [ 9] composer.json
  [10] Controller
  [11] Field
  [12] Hook
  [13] Install file
  [14] Javascript
  [15] Layout
  [16] Module
  [17] Module file
  [18] PhpStorm metadata
  [19] Plugin manager
  [20] Render element
  [21] Service provider
  [22] Template
  [23] Theme
  [24] Theme file
  [25] Theme settings
```

Choose [16] to start a new module and then run [ 2] twice.

**Edit:**

The current Drush version 11 supports also generating entities separately:

```
drush generate entity:content
```

Comment: I think all of chi teck's code generator went into Drush, didn't it?

Comment: Yes, drush initiates a chi-teck dcg Application and enhances it with additional generators. So this is a matter of which drush version depends on which dcg. dcg works stand-alone without drush if you don't want this version restriction.

Comment: Thank you. Now I found that Drush after 11 version also supports chi-teck dcg and you have this functionality there. I was using 10.6.

Comment: @4uk4 actually, if you are using Drush under 11, you can't install dcg 2+ version as Drush requires old dcg

Comment: I would uninstall the old Drush temporarily to install dcg 2+. Especially for entities it's important not to use an outdated code generator.

Comment: yes that is exactly what I did

Answer (score 4):

While Drupal core modules normally implement a single content entity, that isn't a Drupal limit; it is rather the modules that focus on implementing a single functionality and a single entity.

The Aggregator module implements two content entities: the [Aggregator feed](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21aggregator%21src%21Entity%21Feed.php/class/Feed/9.3.x) entity and the [Aggregator feed item](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21aggregator%21src%21Entity%21Item.php/class/Item/9.3.x) entity, for example.

```php
/**
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "aggregator_feed",
 *   label = @Translation("Aggregator feed"),
 *   label_collection = @Translation("Aggregator feeds"),
 *   label_singular = @Translation("aggregator feed"),
 *   label_plural = @Translation("aggregator feeds"),
 *   label_count = @PluralTranslation(
 *     singular = "@count aggregator feed",
 *     plural = "@count aggregator feeds",
 *   ),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "storage" = "Drupal\aggregator\FeedStorage",
 *     "storage_schema" = "Drupal\aggregator\FeedStorageSchema",
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\aggregator\FeedViewBuilder",
 *     "access" = "Drupal\aggregator\FeedAccessControlHandler",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\aggregator\AggregatorFeedViewsData",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\aggregator\FeedForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\aggregator\Form\FeedDeleteForm",
 *       "delete_items" = "Drupal\aggregator\Form\FeedItemsDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\aggregator\FeedHtmlRouteProvider",
 *     },
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/aggregator/sources/{aggregator_feed}",
 *     "edit-form" = "/aggregator/sources/{aggregator_feed}/configure",
 *     "delete-form" = "/aggregator/sources/{aggregator_feed}/delete",
 *   },
 *   field_ui_base_route = "aggregator.admin_overview",
 *   base_table = "aggregator_feed",
 *   render_cache = FALSE,
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "fid",
 *     "label" = "title",
 *     "langcode" = "langcode",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

```php
/**
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "aggregator_item",
 *   label = @Translation("Aggregator feed item"),
 *   label_collection = @Translation("Aggregator feed items"),
 *   label_singular = @Translation("aggregator feed item"),
 *   label_plural = @Translation("aggregator feed items"),
 *   label_count = @PluralTranslation(
 *     singular = "@count aggregator feed item",
 *     plural = "@count aggregator feed items",
 *   ),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "storage" = "Drupal\aggregator\ItemStorage",
 *     "storage_schema" = "Drupal\aggregator\ItemStorageSchema",
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\aggregator\ItemViewBuilder",
 *     "access" = "Drupal\aggregator\FeedAccessControlHandler",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\aggregator\AggregatorItemViewsData"
 *   },
 *   uri_callback = "Drupal\aggregator\Entity\Item::buildUri",
 *   base_table = "aggregator_item",
 *   render_cache = FALSE,
 *   list_cache_tags = { "aggregator_feed_list" },
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "iid",
 *     "label" = "title",
 *     "langcode" = "langcode",
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

It's not a bad idea, implementing more than a content entity in a module. I would only avoid implementing content entities that aren't necessary.

As for why Drush creates a new module for each content/configuration entity, as other users said, that is probably to keep the Drush code simple and because usually that's what is done.